# Error: "/sbin/mount.davfs: mounting failed; the server does not support WebDAV"

Tags: debian, mount, webdav, owncloud

I'm trying to make a WebDAV mount of my ownCloud (Version 10) server to my own machine (Debian 9.4 - only text mode), however, when i executed the "mount" command this error occurred

[image: error_webdav]
error: /sbin/mount.davfs: mounting failed; the server does not support WebDAV

In other machine i used the software WinSCP and take success to make a WebDAV connection, using this parameters

Dir: /remote.php/dav/files/admin/

[image: webdav_winscp]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came to share the solution I found for this problem.
The version of ownCloud that was being used was 10.0.8, but when performing an update to version 10.0.9 the problem with the mount process stopped happening.

For more informations check the official documentation: https://doc.owncloud.org/server/10.0/user_manual/files/access_webdav.html